# Python 2captcha ( Twocaptcha ) asynchronously? (or running any sync class asynchronously?)

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, captcha, blocking

I am using this library which is the official Python wrapper for the 2captcha API service: https://github.com/2captcha/2captcha-python/tree/master/twocaptcha

The code is really simple to integrate but I've been having a problem with figuring out how to run it asynchronously. I've tried editing their code and replacing the instances of `time.sleep` with `asyncio.sleep` but the function is still blocking my event loop. Here is the code I am using to solve the captcha:

```py
import twocaptcha
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha

captchas = TwoCaptcha(API_KEY)

result = captchas.normal(image) # it blocks here
```

I've also tried (and am still) running it in an executor like this:

```py
await self.loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: captchas)
```

But this seems to do nothing at all but I'm sure it's being used because code that follows it still functions. I've also tried putting that into a `while` loop, thinking that maybe it needs to continue to be executed or something, but that didn't change anything either. If I don't use `lambda`, I get a `TypeError` error saying:

```py
'TwoCaptcha' object is not callable
```

but `await self.loop.run_in_executor(None, captchas.normal(*args))` seems useless too. I'm probably doing something stupid cause I'm still kind of a beginner and I've never used `run_in_executor` before.

Anyway, if anyone knows how I can run this without blocking my event loop, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue so here it is for anyone who finds this.

**Previously the blocking call would be made like this:**

```py
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha

solver = TwoCaptcha(API_KEY)

captcha_result = solver.normal(captcha_image) # blocking
```

**But it can be ran asynchronously like this:**

```py
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha

solver = TwoCaptcha(API_KEY)

captcha_result = await captchaSolver(captcha_image) # not blocking

async def captchaSolver(image):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, lambda: solver.normal(image))
        return result
```